# Prove $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arccos\left(\frac{3x^3-3x+4x^2\sqrt{2-x^2}}{5x^2-1}\right)\mathrm dx=\frac{3\pi^2}{8}-2\pi\arctan\frac12$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, trigonometric-integrals

There is [numerical evidence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2CDivide%5B3Power%5B%CF%80%2C2%5D%2C8%5D-2%CF%80arctan%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%5Darccos%5C%2840%29Divide%5B3Power%5Bx%2C3%5D-3x%2B4Power%5Bx%2C2%5DSqrt%5B2-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2C5Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) that

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arccos\left(\frac{3x^3-3x+4x^2\sqrt{2-x^2}}{5x^2-1}\right)\mathrm dx=\frac{3\pi^2}{8}-2\pi\arctan\frac12.$$

> How can this be proved?

Wolfram [does not find](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5B1-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%5Darccos%5C%2840%29Divide%5B3Power%5Bx%2C3%5D-3x%2B4Power%5Bx%2C2%5DSqrt%5B2-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2C5Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D) an antiderivative.

Here is the graph of $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arccos\left(\frac{3x^3-3x+4x^2\sqrt{2-x^2}}{5x^2-1}\right)$.

[image]

Based on recent experience with integrals involving inverse trigonometric functions ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4838976/398708)), I guess a proof may involve a lot of substitutions. But I don't have any insight on how to approach this.

A [search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7D%5Carccos%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B3x%5E3-3x%2B4x%5E2%5Csqrt%7B2-x%5E2%7D%7D%7B5x%5E2-1%7D%5Cright)%5C%20dx%24&p=1) on approachzero did not turn up anything similar.

**Context**

If this can be proved, then we can answer the question [Probability that the centroid of a triangle is inside its incircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4887813/398708), via @user170231's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4889751/398708).

**How I found the conjectured closed form**

In my comment to @user170231's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4889751/398708) to the linked question, I note that the probability in that question is $1-\frac{12}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}(y-x_+)dy$, which is equivalent to $1-\frac{12}{\pi^2}(\int_0^{\pi/2}ydy-I)\approx0.457993176$, where $I$ is the integral in this question.

Wolfram [suggests](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=0.457993176) that $0.457993176$ is $4-24\left(\frac{\arctan(1/2)}{\pi}\right)$, which implies that $I=\frac{3\pi^2}{8}-2\pi\arctan\frac12$.

Comment: "Factoring" out $\sqrt{5}x-1$ from the numerator of the $\arccos$ argument should be possible. From there, we should be able to draw triangles and make use of double angle identities to simplify the integrand.

Comment: Considering the form of the $\arccos$ argument, the initial trick [to this other integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4878696/) may be useful.